# Why does my code end up with an empty data reader after initially running for a few times?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I am using these two methods.

```
public List<Request> GetRequest(int? com = null, int? req = null, int? st = null)
        {
            List<SqlParameter> sqlParameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
            string query = string.Empty;

            if (com.HasValue)
            {
                sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                {
                    ParameterName = "@Id",
                    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                    Value = com.Value
                });

                query = string.Concat(query, "   AND id = @Id");
            }

            if (req.HasValue)
            {
                sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                {
                    ParameterName = "@Rid",
                    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                    Value = req.Value
                });

                query = string.Concat(query, @"   AND req = @Rid");
            }

            if (st.HasValue)
            {
                sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
                {
                    ParameterName = "@on",
                    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                    Value = st.Value
                });

                query = string.Concat(query, "   AND st= @on");
            }

            
            query = string.Concat(initial, query);
            return GetRequests(query, sqlParameters);
        }

        private List<Request> GetRequests(string query, List<SqlParameter> sqlParameters = null)
        {
            List<Request> requests = new List<Request>();

            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_sqlConnectionStr)
            {
                using SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);

                if (sqlParameters != null && sqlParameters.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (SqlParameter sqlParameter in sqlParameters)
                    {
                        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter);
                    }
                }
                sqlCommand.Connection.Open();

                using SqlDataReader dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(queryString);


                if (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dataReader);
                    requests.Add(new RequestHeader()
                    {
                        com = dataReader.GetFieldValue<int>(0),
                        req = dataReader.GetFieldValue<Guid>(1),
                        st = dataReader.GetFieldValue<int>(3),
                   
                    });
                }
            }

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(requests.Count);
            return requests;


        }
```

In the first method initial is just a select statement for a table and the conditions have been added later on in the method through concatenation.
When I run the query in the sql server, it runs fine as well. All the values like com, st and req are also passed down correctly.

Comment: Hi, yes, sorry about that. will fix it right away.

Comment: SSMS is the IDE-like application, not the data engine. Saying you are using SSMS for your data engine is like saying Visual Studio is the programming language you are using; it's not particularly helpful. As SSMS is proprietary to Microsoft data engines, presumably you are using SQL Server here.

Comment: Just a sidenote: If this is getting used frequently, you may want to consider different methods to build that string. Like using `StringBuilder` or something similar.

Comment: What means "data reader initially read a few rows but after a while stopped containing any values"? You use `if (dataReader.Read())`, so there is no loop and the list contains only one item at maximum.

Comment: My bet is : there are no rows for the corresponding where clause. You could debug that : the query string along with parameters and check with SSMS if there are such rows

Comment: @TimSchmelter sorry about the ambiguity but what i mean is when i ran the program, a first couple of time, the data reader wasn't empty. When I ran it again, it's supposed to add each iteration in the log. So at first it seemed fine, but later on every time i run the program, it was empty. Thank you!

Comment: @Cid tried that and the query works in the server. Thank you!

Comment: @Fildor it is getting used frequently. Is there a reason for a different approach? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `if(dataReader.Read())` so you only get the results for one row.

You can also simplify your code a little.

```cs
private List<Request> GetRequests(string query, List<SqlParameter> sqlParameters = null)
{
    List<Request> requests = new List<Request>();
    using SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_sqlConnectionStr);
    using SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
    if (sqlParameters != null)
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParameters.ToArray());

    sqlCommand.Connection.Open();
    using SqlDataReader dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(queryString);
    while (dataReader.Read())
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dataReader);
        requests.Add(new RequestHeader()
        {
            com = dataReader.GetFieldValue<int>(0),
            req = dataReader.GetFieldValue<Guid>(1),
            st = dataReader.GetFieldValue<int>(3),
        });
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(requests.Count);
    return requests;
}
```